# How to scrape a data from a dynamic website containing Javascript using Python?

Tags: javascript, excel, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from https://www.doordash.com/food-delivery/chicago-il-restaurants/

The idea is to scrape all the data regarding the different restaurant listings on the website. The site is divided into different cities, but I only require restaurant data for ***Chicago***.

All restaurant listings for the city have to be scraped along with any other relevant data about the respective restaurants (Ex: Reviews, Rating, Cuisine, address, state etc). I need to capture all the respective details(currently 4,326 listings) for the city in the Excel.

I have tried to extract the restaurant name, cuisine, ratings and review inside the class named "StoreCard_root___1p3uN". But No datas have been displayed. The output is blank.

````
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"D:\python project\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://www.doordash.com/food-delivery/chicago-il-restaurants/")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="SeoApp"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]""").click()

posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("StoreCard_root___1p3uN")

for post in posts:
    print(post.text) ```
````

Comment: What is your question? Have you received an error whilst trying to scrape data from this website? If so please tell us what error you are trying to solve. I'm not understanding what you require

Comment: make your life easy man ! use API https://api.doordash.com/v2/seo_city_stores/?delivery_city_slug=chicago-il-restaurants&store_only=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `API` url as the data rendered from it actually via `XHR` request.

iterate over the `API` link below and `scrape` whatever you want.

https://api.doordash.com/v2/seo_city_stores/?delivery_city_slug=chicago-il-restaurants&store_only=true&limit=50&offset=0

You will just loop over this parameter `offset=0` by increasing it +50 each time as each page will shown `50` items till you reach `4300` as it's the last page ! simply by `range(0, 4350, 50)`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = []
for item in range(0, 4350, 50):
    print(f"Extracting item# {item}")
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://api.doordash.com/v2/seo_city_stores/?delivery_city_slug=chicago-il-restaurants&store_only=true&limit=50&offset={item}").json()
    for item in r['store_data']:
        item = (item['name'], item['city'], item['category'],
                item['num_ratings'], item['average_rating'], item['average_cost'])
        data.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=['Name', 'City', 'Category', 'Num Ratings', 'Average Ratings', 'Average Cost'])
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
print("done")
```

Sample of Output:

[image]

View Output online: [Click Here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=e740575ab41a17897efd7ddab9c9fd69ca2ee63fd8ffb3fd654ce529416c9d1c773852d3791d39addb9dec1515469326649ee7425eeba02100a490cb98d643b3)

Full Data is here: [Click Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c86acd31ad18883762bf3c7cf8cce93d/output.csv)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203753/discussion-on-answer-by--c-how-to-scrape-a-data-from-a-dynamic-websi).

Comment: How do we get address ?

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this issue too, but I solved it using selenium and BeautifulSoup by doing the following:

1. Make sure the algorithm clicks button to reveal Menu and prices if necessary
2. The menu and prices have to be processed because they will might come off as nested list after the extraction from parsing so the get_text() function won't work on them right away.
   The code and explanation can be found in this medium article

[Tackling empty list web scraping with selenium](https://tadeogundele.medium.com/web-scraping-with-selenium-why-your-code-works-but-returns-an-empty-list-still-f736cbe761a2)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out the API that αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη mentions. They also had an endpoint for restaurant info.

URL [https://api.doordash.com/v2/restaurant/[restaurantId]/](https://api.doordash.com/v2/restaurant/%5BrestaurantId%5D/)

It was working until recently when it started returning {"detail":"Request was throttled."}

Has anyone had the same issue / found a workaround?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31564349)